# What's the best way to merge consecutive Observables' results?

Tags: angular, rxjs, concatenation

Let's say I have an Observable which results in an Object of 3 arrays like this :

```
    results = {
        type1: [...],
        type2: [...],
        type3: [...],
    };
```

Is there a rxjs operator which allows me to combine multiple observables and their results in order to have a final result like this :

```
    results1 = {
        type1: [1, 2],
        type2: ['ab', 'cd'],
        type3: ['foo', 'bar'],
    };

    results2 = {
        type1: [3, 4, 5],
        type2: ['ef', 'gh', 'ij'],
        type3: ['ban', 'jo', 'vi'],
    };

    final_results = {
        type1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        type2: ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij'],
        type3: ['foo', 'bar', 'ban', 'jo', 'vi'],
    };
```

?????

For the record I'm using Angular 2+ and typescript, and I want to keep using Observable streams and rxjs operators, but according to their documentation I'm not sure they're one which could do something like 'deep merging ??'

Thanks for helping

Comment: There are multiple operators which can merge the data of two observables, but concatenating the values is something that is logic-specific. You can use one of the operators to merge data and concatenate it manually.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the scan operator:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html

It is similar to the [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) operator, but the reduce operator will only emit at the end of the stream. The scan operator will emit the intermediate value every time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't observable-related, this is plain old Javascript.

The only operator you have to know is `combineLatest` :

```js
combineLatest(results1$, results2$).pipe(
  map((results1, results2) => {
    const ret = {};
    Object.keys(results1).foreEach(key => ret[key] = results1[key].concat(results2[key]));
    return ret;
  })
).subscribe(res => console.log(res)); // should display your expected result
```

Don't be mistaken : RxJS operators manipulate the stream (the Observable itself), not the data in it.

If you want to handle the internal data, this becomes Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) operator to aggregate a single result from many emitted values. 
It's up to you to merge the single arrays since this is not related to rxjs

Simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cffyyh